# UML and ethertap: what I miss?

Tags: bridge, tap, user-mode-linux

I want to run my UML istance with network
In the host machine I create the script

```
USER=myname
BRIDGENAME=br0
tunctl -t tap0 -u $USER
ip link set tap0 up
/usr/sbin/brctl addif $BRIDGENAME tap0
ip addr add 10.2.0.5/24 dev tap0
```

The tap0 is created and no error is reported.
After this I launch the uml istance

```
/usr/bin/linux ubda=fsroot mem=1024M con0=fd:0,fd:1 con=pts eth0=ethertap,tap0,10.2.0.5
```

Then I enter in the uml istance with minicom and I try to configure the network

```
ip addr add 10.2.0.6/24 dev eth0
ip route add default via 10.2.0.5
Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.
```

What I miss? Why is not comunicating?
I have tried also using the classical iptables rules for natting

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -A FORWARD -i tap0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o tap0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br0 -j MASQUERADE
```

but nothing change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, In the configuration on UML I forgot
this line

```
ip link set eth0 up
```

before the route line

I have also change the method, using enp1s0 instead of bridge, and ethertune instead of ethertap

a)first I create tap0

```
sudo ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap
sudo ip addr add 10.2.0.5/24 dev tap0
ip link set tap0 up
```

b)then I apply the iptables rules

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tap0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp1s0  -o tap0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

c)and finally run the instance

```
linux ubda=fsroot mem=1024M con0=fd:0,fd:1 con=pts eth0=tuntap,tap0,10.2.0.5
```

d)in the istance I configured the network

```
ip addr add 10.2.0.6/24
ip link set eth0 up
ip route add default via 10.2.0.5
```

Works ok